# What is the forward protocol for FBB?

Tags: packet

Does anyone know the forwarding protocol used by FBB?

I am working on a program in C# and looking for the protocol to make compressed forwarding etc.

Comment: I don't know anything about it myself, but a quick web search shows there seems to be [documentation](http://www.f6fbb.org/protocole.html) of the forwarding protocol. Could you edit your question to add more detail on what you need to know, that isn't covered by existing documentation?

Comment: Please mark as answered

Comment: Only you can do that, by marking a specific answer as accepted. I've reposted my comment as an answer so I can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about it myself, but a quick web search shows there seems to be [documentation here](http://www.f6fbb.org/protocole.html) of the forwarding protocol.